# angular directive d3 stuck when hidden on mobile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, angularjs-directive

I have a simple directive that renders a d3 svg word cloud.

The directive should be visible only on desktop, so I remove it on mobile with bootstrap class: "xs-hidden"

the problem is the browser tab gets stuck as angular probably looks for the directive but cant find it.

I altered and added the render method of the directive scope,
the tab gets stuck when we call

```
 layout.start();
```

only when the div is hidden with "hidden-xs"

** tab gets stuck means - it simply shows "loading" the page is loaded but the page is stuck, I cant refresh, I need to close the tab.

some code:

```
 link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      //stuff....
      scope.render(['word', 'word2']);

      scope.render = function(words) {
                if (!words || !words.length) return;

                var maxSize = d3.max(words, function(d) { return d.count; });
                var minSize = d3.min(words, function(d) { return d.count; });
                var fontScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([minSize, maxSize])
                    .range([16, 40]);

                var layout = d3.layout.cloud()
                    .size([svgWidth, 350])
                    .words(words.map(function(d) {
                        return {text: d.word, size: d.count};
                    }))
                    .padding(10)
                    .rotate(function() { return 0; })
                    .font("Arvo")
                    .fontSize(function(d) { return fontScale(d.size) })
                    .fontWeight(700)
                    .spiral('rectangular')
                    .on("end", draw);


                //when this is called the tab get stuck and must be closed
                layout.start();

                function draw(words) {
                    //dont care
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hidden is not the same thing as removed from the DOM.  There's no reason why it couldn't find it just because it wasn't visible.  You'll need to show more code since what you've shown so far is probably not related to the issue. Please see [MCVE]

Comment: Thanks @DavidL just altered the code, and pinpointed it to a better spot. any ideas maybe?

Comment: What do you mean by "stuck".  It won't open or it kills off the tab completely?  Where is `scope.render` called from?

Comment: Tnx David, altered it again, it is called inside the "link" method of the directive

Comment: Based on your update, stuck says to me "massive memory leak...something is killing the page".  Have you watched the tab size to see if it's increasing?  Have you debugged it?

Comment: that is what I'm saying, I cant do nothing except of closing the tab....

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your element where word cloud needs to be rendered is present in DOM or not ?

The class you mentioned has:

```
  .hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
```

So element may not be in DOM when you try to render the word cloud.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand... :/

Comment: can you put snippet where you attach word cloud ?  Something like d3.select. I am assuming the element selected may not be present in dom when layout.start(); runs

Comment: you are right, the div that contains the svg is hidden with "hidden-xs". I solved that by checking if the div is visible or not and only then rendered

Comment: yes of course, just please update your post, it has some mistakes like: world could instead of word cloud